# Concatenating PHP session in a single quoted string

Tags: php, string, session, cygwin, system

I have to create an output file (with the compilation errors) into a file.
My initial approach was this:

```
$output = system("C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -c '/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/g++.exe /cygdrive/c/Server/www/Codice/chorva.cpp -o /cygdrive/c/Server/www/Codice/chorva.exe >> compile.log 2>&1'");
```

And this code worked.

But when I added sessions, I can't get it to right. What am i doing wrong?
All help is much appreciated!

```
$command = "/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/g++.exe /cygdrive/c/Server/www/Codice/LOGS/".$_SESSION['username']."/chorva.cpp -o /cygdrive/c/Server/www/Codice/LOGS/".$_SESSION['username']."/chorva.exe >> compile.log 2>&1";    
$output = system('C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -c'.$command);
```

EDIT: I did use `session_start()` and the session username does have a value

Comment: maybe the missin space after -c' in the second command?

Comment: did you check the values returned by `$_SESSION`?

Comment: Yup @Cristian it does have a value

Comment: Can you show us the contents of output variable?

Comment: @Cristian It doesn't have any value, that's actually the problem. But it should retrieve compilation errors

Comment: Yes, I've also noticed that you used slashes and backslashes, I think you should change all slashes to backslashes,  windows is quite sensible about that

Comment: @Cristian Hmm ok I'll try that.. But the first code did work. So i'll update you if that works. Thanks

Comment: @Cristian that didn't work too :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you should enable PHP session by placing `session_start();` at top of the code so PHP could initialize session cookie.

To ensure that session is set and value is not empty use `isset($_SESSION['username'])` and/or `!empty($_SESSION['username'])`.

I recommend using `var_dump($_SESSION);` to see if the value is acually set.

Comment: I added session_start() before that. Sorry for not mentioning. And I also echo -ed the session, and it does have a value.

Comment: As I noticed, there is no apostrophes around the command as it is in first example that worked.

Comment: aaaah... it has i just changed the double quotes into single quotes (or what you call apostrophe)

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work. Here's how I did it:

```
$un = $_SESSION['username'];
$command = "/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/g++.exe /cygdrive/c/Server/www/Codice/LOGS/".$un."/chorva.cpp -o /cygdrive/c/Server/www/Codice/LOGS/".$un."/chorva.exe >> LOGS/".$un."/compile.log 2>&1";
$output = system("C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -c '".$command);
```

So I still added an apostrophe there. Otherwise, it doesn't work